# Change css class based on url slug in OctoberCMS

Tags: html, css, twig, octobercms, slug

So I am trying to work on a OctoberCMS theme for my own project. The goal is to have the whole navigation header in a different color, based on the page the user is on. Seems pretty simple but I was after hours of trying still not able to manage.

So my idea was to add a different css class based on the page the user is on. For *https://example.com/foo/bar* a class like this should be showing: *navbar-foo*

I found OctoberCMS Twig has a option called `this.param.tab` which should return exactly *"foo"*, so I thought of this:

```
{% if this.param.tab == 'foo' %}
    <nav class="navbar-foo">
{% if this.param.tab == 'bar' %}
    <nav class="navbar-bar">
```

And so on. The thing is, that would take up a lot of space and I didn't think it was that clean of a way. Also the class would need to be on multiple elements which would kind of make it a bit unreadable. So i thought I'll just solve it like this:

```
{% set slug = this.param.tab %}
<nav class="navbar-{ slug }">
    <div class="navbar-menu-{ slug }
```

This didn't work. First I thought it didn't work because I didn't insert the twig right for it to be counted as a string in the html. The other thing I thought I did wrong was that `this.param.tab` returns an Array and not a string. So i tried different ideas to insert it into the class attribute and change it from array to string when I realised, that `this.param.tab` was empty.So I tried wrapping it into a div and just display it like that. But that just turned out empty. I tried to `{{ dump(this.param.tab) }}` which also turned out empty.

So it seemed to me that `this.param.tab`actually did not return anything. As the code is in the *header.htm* I thought maybe it needed to be in the main called file, as the *header.htm* is just a partial that gets inserted. So I tried the *layout.htm* and I tried *home.htm* (layout is the file, that defines the layout of the page, where the partials/page are inserted and home.htm is the file that actually contains the slug and the other code of the page the user is visiting). But that didn't do anything either.

So i'm not entirely sure what is wrong here. Does `this.param.tab` even actually work? or is there a better way I should do this?

If you need additional information ask, but I thought it won't matter because it is just a basic October setup and the theme is just twig, javascript and scss.

Comment: can you share your pages slug information

Comment: sure. What do you mean by pages slug information? It's just at the start of the htm file where I wrote: url = "/foo/bar"

Comment: hmmm ok, now I am not sure how you expect `this.param.tab`to be filled with correct data, as you are not setting it or doinga nythig for it, or its coneected any how , we are missing anything

Comment: you should go throught : https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/pages first then you are able to use slug `params` correctly and you can set your class correctly :)

Comment: Yeah but I'm doing it exactly like that. It even says on the page you don't need to go through PHP but can just use "this.page", so I'm assuming "this.param" should also work without PHP.

Comment: I added answer how you can use `url` may be it can help you

Answer (score 2):

if you just need `url` for your condition you can do like this

```
{% set slug = this.page.settings.url|replace({'/': '-'} %}
    <nav class="navbar{{ slug }}">
        <div class="navbar-menu{{ slug }}
```

> Now if you set your `url = "/foo/bar"` your class name will be `navbar-foo-bar`, if you set your `url = "/test"` your class name will be `navbar-test`, if you set your `url = "/bla/ok/test"` your class name will be `navbar-bla-ok-test`.

### with params

> you need to set your url to => `/foo/:tab` and then you can get `tab` value in to `{{ this.param.tab }}`

so once you set url like that then you can get values like this

if you use url http://example.com/foo/bar -> `{{ this.param.tab }}` will be `foo`

```
<nav class="navbar-{{ this.param.tab }}"> -> will be  -> <nav class="navbar-foo">
```

if you use url  http://example.com/foo/test -> `{{ this.param.tab }}` will be `test`

```
<nav class="navbar-{{ this.param.tab }}"> -> will be  -> <nav class="navbar-test">
```

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: Great idea thanks! Though sadly that won't work. I thought of something similar, but the thing is I only need the "foo". No additional slugs, only the first thing after the domain.

Comment: ok np,interesting may be i am not able to understand your issue, best of luck for solving  that

Comment: no worries ;) You see, I don't need the full url like "/foo/bar" but only "foo". And "this.param.tab" should return that but it just doesn't. But thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: ok  once moew updated answer can you check that if that can help

Comment: ok thanks to your answer I figured out that I was stupid. I now see two options. option 1: use "this.page.url" and strip away the parts I don't need or add a "data = "foo"" on top of every site and call it with *that.page.data". I chose the second thing because it seemed easier. I don't 100% like this way but I guess it's the only thing I can do.